# eclipse plugin won't install any more

Tags: windows-7, eclipse-plugin, 32-bit

I received a new version of a plugin of a project I work in collaboration with other people.I copied it over the old version in the /plugin directory. Eclispe (3.7.2 on Win7) ignored the plugin (don’t show up in the Help/About Eclipse/Installed Plugins). I put the old version back (I put an “_old” at the end of the .jar file) and it worked again but the plugin’s command in the menu appeared with a “%” character at the beginning. After some more copying of old/new version in the /plugin directory, even the old plugin won’t install. I put back an acient original version of the plugin, but still not working. It just stop suddenly working. I checked my permissions on the /plugin directory, started Eclipse as an administrator, but no success.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should put both versions in plugins directory only if they have different versions in plugin.xml definitions but even in this case only one of them probably will be active i.e. will add its contributions to Eclipse. You should use copy/paste actions to provide additionals to Eclipse carefully, plugins and features directories are not supposed for manual usage. To manage your plugins easily follow the [dropins directory](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fp2_dropins_format.html) usage. For now the best you can do is to remove all versions of your custom plugin and run Eclipse to the clean workbench.

Comment: I removed all version and run Eclipse to clean wokbench. This not solved the problem. Apparently it's related to permissions. Another option is to reinstall Eclipse, but since it's time consuming (reintall other plugins and setup), is there another option ?

Comment: Try to install your ancient version of plugin using Eclipse Installation Manager (install from jar or archive, don't remember really) Did you try dropins folder?

Comment: I managed to reinstall older plugins by launching eclipse with the " -clean" parameter. The last version of the plugin wont's install but at leas I cans use the older ones.